# Custom Background colors with different gradients

Tags: android, android-layout, background

Actually, I want to apply this as a background for my Android App pages but I want to write it in XML and I don't know where should I start from ?[image]

Comment: convert to svg and import as vector asset. to my knowledge, use of full screen xml drawables causes performance issues. it takes hell lot of time to render that. best practice is to use jpg images wherever possible

Comment: but if i used it as an image i need to resize it according to different screen sizes and densities right ?

Comment: put the image in nodpi folder for that. using different size of drawables is used to enhance the performance. just to know the difference, see the android monitor for different cases discussed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you know how to do it. `Gradient`, `GradientDrawable` is the key.

Good to read this huge drawable tutorial/source : [Drawables](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Drawables). For Gradient search this header : **Gradient Colored Shapes**

Also shorter one : [gradient-drawable-in-android](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/gradient-drawable-in-android.html).

Also if you want to do it thru `styles.xml` just add this line to your Theme. It will add `background.xml` to all your activities by default.

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
```

Don't forget you can set simple colors too like that :

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">#AA123456</item>
```

If you want to change Activity background color, background drawable programmatically, I am using this way :

```
//for color
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(yourdesiredcolor);
//for drawable,eg gradient
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackground(yourdesireddrawable);
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you. Happy coding.

Comment: +1 for the amswer, but there are few performance related points missing here. if yoi could add them too, then future visitors of this answer will be benefited

Comment: @MohammedAtif thanks for good pointing.I answered this question quickly because I was outside. You can suggest edits for this answer and I really exciting to see them.